# Realm migration is crashing on Android 7.1.2

Tags: android, realm, realm-migration

The app is crashing with a realm exception that some tables do not exist in the schema. I made three tables in Realm Database and created the migration for it. The app update(migration) is working for all versions of Android, but for Android 7.1.2 is crashing the app with the mentioned exception.

Example: I had version 1.0 of the app installed on my phone, then I installed the Android 7.1.2 update, then I updated my app to version 2.0 which contains the three new tables I mentioned.

Did anyone encounter this scenario? Why would the migration work for previous versions of Android but on 7.1.2 doesn't work?

Realm version: 3.1.4

Comment: Have you filed an issue on Github ( https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues )? That sounds kinda severe. If you have a sample project for it that's even better.

Comment: Hey @AdrianPopovici, do you have any evidence of this?  Do you have code that will reproduce the crash?  Can you include it in the GitHub issue?

Comment: We are tracking this issue here: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/4651